# Mallet: Alphabets don't match exceptions

Tags: java, mallet

I try to implement a document classifier with Mallet in Java. I already have a file that essential contains feature values. So I don't want to run through an entire `raw text` processing pipeline.

A line in my feature file looks like this at the moment (2 features, ID and NrOfToken, document label is "A")

`ID=3 NrofTokens=279.0 A`

I try to read in this file and put it into a classifier like this:

```
Pipe instancePipe = new SerialPipes(new Pipe[] {
                new CharSequence2TokenSequence(),
                new TokenSequence2FeatureSequence(),
                new Target2Label(),
        });

        InstanceList trainData = new InstanceList(instancePipe);
        InstanceList testData = new InstanceList(instancePipe);

        Reader trainFileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileTrain), "UTF-8");
        trainData.addThruPipe(new LineGroupIterator(trainFileReader, Pattern.compile("^\\s*$"), true));

        Reader testFileReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileTest), "UTF-8");
        testData.addThruPipe(new LineGroupIterator(testFileReader, Pattern.compile("^\\s*$"), true));

        // Create a classifier trainer, and use it to create a classifier
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        ClassifierTrainer naiveBayesTrainer = new NaiveBayesTrainer();
        Classifier classifier = naiveBayesTrainer.train(trainData);
```

At the moment I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alphabets don't match: Instance: [6, null], InstanceList: [6, 0]
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.add(InstanceList.java:335)
    at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.addThruPipe(InstanceList.java:267)
    at
```

Anyone an idea why the Alphabet is breaking?

Comment: Could someone please help on this query? Am also facing the issue while running the Topic modelling code from http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/.

Comment: Is anyone facing the same issue in 2020 with the mallet version 3.0.8?
What I found is it happens in rare scenarios. I have also look for official documentation but I haven't found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but I found the exceptions in Mallet not very informative so far. I also got this error, changing my regex that parses the data lines and removing an empty line at the end made it go away.

i.e. the regex in this part

```
CsvIterator reader = new CsvIterator(new FileReader(tempTrainPath), "(\\w+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.*)", 3, 2, 1);
testInstances.addThruPipe(reader);
```

At the end of a whole day of debugging, I was too annoyed to try out which of the two was the actual culprit. But maybe this info helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to evaluate a classifier from the command line. Adding `--use-pipe-from train_input.mallet` option as described at https://mallet-dev.cs.umass.narkive.com/NFtumW1r/mallet-2-0-7-ge-maxent-alphabets-don-t-match solved the problem.